# Can I use didReceiveRemoteNotification to create local notifications?

Tags: ios, objective-c, apple-push-notifications

We are planning to have end to end encryption in our messaging app, so cannot display user message as the `APNS` push notification message directly. So we are planning to send a silent Push notification, decrypt the message in the iOS App's background mode and then display the plain text message as a local notification

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application
didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo
fetchCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UIBackgroundFetchResult result))handler
```

Comment: Yes it will work. The same technique can be applied for (pseudo) notification filtering (decide if you really want to show a notification based on some dynamic parameters)

Comment: May I know, why the downvote  :-/

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you could event just send the silent notification (using the contentAvailable flag in the payload) but only use the notification to notify your app of a message availability, in which the delegate method then downloads the message from a database on your secure servers then pushes the local notification to the device like you are saying.

That way you aren't even giving apple the opportunity to decrypt your message because it won't even go through their servers.